# "module [...] is defined in multiple files" error from Haskell compilation

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am getting the following error when i compile with the -Wall option.

```
ghc -o -Wall polycake polycake.hs
```

When I don't use the option my code compiles fine and runs as expected. What does this mean?

```
<no location info>: error:
    module ‘main:Polycake’ is defined in multiple files: polycake.hs
                                                         polycake.hs
```

Comment: What's your command line?

Comment: just default, bash shell in mac os x

Comment: No, I mean what is the exact command you're using to get that error?

Comment: ghc -o -Wall polycake polycake.hs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-o` option expects the output file name as the next argument - it does not care whether that argument starts with a dash or not. So `-o -Wall` sets the output file name to `-Wall` (and does not actually enable warnings).

So the two left over arguments are `polycake` and `polycake.hs`, which `ghc` interprets as input file names. When an input file name does not exist and does not already end with the `.hs` extension, `ghc` will try to add that extension. So `ghc polycake polycake.hs` will try to compile `polycake.hs` twice. This leads to your error.

PS: The output file name defaults to the input file name without the extension, so you don't need the `-o` option at all in this case.